# Filter outliers in DataFrame rows based on a recursive time-interval

Tags: python, pandas, datetime64

I have the following DataFrame `df`:

```
ds                  y
2018-10-01 00:00    1.23
2018-10-01 01:00    2.21
2018-10-01 02:00    6.40
...                 ...
2018-10-02 00:00    3.21
2018-10-02 01:00    3.42
2018-10-03 02:00    2.99
...                 ...
```

That means that I have one value for `y` per each hour.
I would like to filter the rows so that the values which are not inside the 6-sigma interval (3*std, -3*std) are dropped.

I'm able to do this for the entire DataFrame this way:

```
df = df[np.abs(df.y-df.y.mean()) <= (3*df.y.std())]
```

But I would like to do this in a per-day basis.

Please note that `ds` is a `datetime64[ns]` and `y` a `float64`.

Also, since my ultimate goal is to exclude outliers from data, can you suggest other viable options to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
g = df.groupby(df.index.floor('D'))['y']
df[(np.abs(df.y - g.transform('mean')) <= (3*g.transform('std')))]
```